# What does QBD stand for?

Tags: fuel, terminology

I recently heard the term QBD which the [Aviation Dictionary](http://www.aviationdictionary.org/QBD) explains is the fuel endurance in terms of hours. If it is an acronym, what is its expansion? If not, what is it derived from?

Comment: @VivianjeetSinghSudan There is also a more polite way to let members know that their question could have been answered with a bit of Google-Fu. A "Welcome to Aviation.SE" as the start of your comment especially with new users can make the difference. ;)

Comment: Welcome to Aviation.SE, topher! :)

Comment: @VivianjeetSinghSudan I did and found the explanation as in the question but no information on its origins. Google is subjective.

Comment: We don't direct people to Google; Google directs people to us.

Comment: I smell pride, @MarcksThomas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It comes from [Q codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_code) for morse communication. They where set up without a clear rhyme or reason that I can see besides being ordered alphabetically.

Comment: I'm not sure you can even say they are grouped alphabetically. QRJ? ("How many words have you to send?") doesn't have much in common with QRM? ("Are you being interfered with?"), just to mention one example.